# Pandas timing for filter, rename, and add columns

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to debug a slow script and got myself very confused about the timing of different operations in pandas. Maybe there are great docs for this somewhere but I haven't found them yet.

My test scripts is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# Set up simple timing.
times = []
labels = []
times.append(datetime.datetime.now())

# Build a dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20000,2), columns=['x', 'y'])
labels.append('Build DataFrame')
times.append(datetime.datetime.now())

# Filter the dataframe.
df = df[df.x > .5]
labels.append('Filter')
times.append(datetime.datetime.now())

# Rename some stuff.
df.rename(
    columns={
        'x': 'X',
        'y': 'Y',
    }, inplace=True, copy=False
)
labels.append('Rename columns')
times.append(datetime.datetime.now())

# Add a column.
df['n'] = 1
labels.append('Add column')
times.append(datetime.datetime.now())

print(df)

# Print out times in seconds.
print([labels[i] + ': ' + str((times[i + 1] - times[i]).total_seconds() * 1000.0)
        for i in range(len(times) - 1)])
print('Total: ' + str((times[-1] - times[0]).total_seconds() * 1000.0))
```

Which gives me times of:

```
['Build DataFrame: 1.19', 'Filter: 1.285',
'Rename columns: 16.884', 'Add column: 0.724']

Total: 20.083
```

If I'm understanding rename right I shouldn't be copying anything just updating names so should talk almost no time. This is born out if I re-arrange things to get.

```
['Build DataFrame: 1.613', 'Rename columns: 0.702',
'Filter: 2.664', 'Add column: 18.002']

Total: 22.981
```

Tt then appears that adding the column is taking all the time. Re-arranging again, I have made everything super fast?

```
['Build DataFrame: 1.05', 'Rename columns: 0.364',
'Add column: 0.921', 'Filter: 1.52']

Total: 3.855
```

If I add another column, this time using df['m'] = np.random.rand(df.shape[0]) so that each element has its own value, I end up with.

```
['Build DataFrame: 1.015', 'Rename columns: 0.324',
'Add column: 0.473', 'Filter: 1.247', 'Add column: 18.497']

Total: 21.556
```

I can again speed things up by pushing the column add before the filter.

```
['Build DataFrame: 1.022', 'Rename columns: 0.439',
'Add column: 0.51', 'Add column: 0.58', 'Filter: 4.192']

Total: 6.743
```

Clearly the filtering and copying are the only expensive operations here, and no matter what order I do them I get a consistent `print(df)` output.

My guess for what is going on here is that the filter simple store a mask, but doesn't actually force a copy until it has to. By adding a column I force that copy. I don't get why renaming would force that copy.

Is there a way to manually force that copy for testing?

**UPDATE** for completeness.
Using the nitis `df = (df[df.X > .5]).copy()

```
['Build DataFrame: 0.989', 'Filter: 1.578', 'Rename columns: 0.362',
'Add column: 0.441']
Total: 3.37
```

Btw my 'highly scientific' timing system has a measurement error of ~ 1ms, so that's on the level that I care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
df = df[df.X > .5]
```

with,

```
df = (df[df.X > .5]).copy()
```

Comment: Yep that works great, forcing the copy gives a huge speed up.